# Trying to import GitLab repository to Azure repository but I am getting the below error

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-repos

> Import request cannot be processed due to one of the following reasons:
>
> Clone URL is incorrect.
> Clone URL requires authorization.

NOTE: I am getting this error even though I am providing the correct username and password. And I am able to clone the repository locally with the same clone url.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using credentials (username/password) to clone the repository, that should mean its URL is an HTTPS one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60334237/6309) suggests an issue with an empty repository or a wrong PAT.
The last suggestions reminds me you should try and use a token as your password, instead of your GitLab account password. See if you can create a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html), and use that as a password.